# how to complete a mysql fiddle with a field that contains multiple values?

Tags: mysql

Please have a look at [the following mysql fiddle ...](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c7e5d2)

Now there is only inserted one last value, which is '18'.
Instead of inserting only '18' I would like to insert for example '3; 4; 9; 18'
so I would like that field to contain multiple values.

What changes do I need to make to the above MYSQL fiddle to get the scheme accepted for multiple values as well?

Comment: Noooooooooooooo. See normalisation

Comment: **Do not store multiple values in a single cell** or you'll be violating the [very first normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form) of the normalization principles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To store a list of semicolon separated values you have to change the field type of your last value to a type which supports string storage. For example you can use `varchar`, `char` or `text`.

See the updated [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2202ff) for a possible solution.

Anyway, I don't no much about your use case but usually storing such a list is a sign of a bad data model.

Comment: great, thanks for your answer, now I see, when changing, I had overeen that I left INT where it should have been varchar, char or text. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: @PiotrLinski, your welcome please don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: @PiotrLinski, please take a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work